# Polly continue after X retries

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, polly

I'm using Polly in a Xamarin project which works pretty great. The problem I'm facing is that after 2 retries it should continue the method, but for some reason it gets stuck and keeps retrying. Does anyone know how I can do this?

```
private async Task<List<EventDto>> GetEventsErrorRemoteAsync()
{
    List<EventDto> conferences = null;

    if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected) 
    {
        // Retrying a specific amount of times (5)
        // In this case will wait for
        //  1 ^ 2 = 2 seconds then
        //  2 ^ 2 = 4 seconds then
        //  3 ^ 2 = 8 seconds then
        //  4 ^ 2 = 16 seconds then
        //  5 ^ 2 = 32 seconds
        conferences = await Policy
            .Handle<Exception>()
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(
                retryCount: 2, 
                sleepDurationProvider:retryAttempt => 
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow (2, retryAttempt)), 
                onRetry: (exception, timeSpan, context) => 
                {
                    var ex = (ApiException)exception;

                    //Do something with exception. Send to insights (now hockeyapp)
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.ReasonPhrase} | 
                        TimeSpan: {timeSpan.Seconds}");
                    return;
                }).ExecuteAsync(async () => 
                    await _eventService.GetEventsWithError());
    }
    return conferences;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question answered in detail on the identical Github issue: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/106

The Policy is not stuck keeping retrying.  Rather, if the final attempt made by the retry policy at executing the delegate within `.ExecuteAsync()` still throws, the retry policy will rethrow this final exception.  As you are not catching and handling that exception, the method is naturally not continuing to the return statement.